# Why does GRPC generate template classes?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

In the abstract it's odd for a code generator to generate types for c++'s own code generation techniques rather than just generating the required code. Why does GRPC do this? Why not just further parameterize the grpc code generator (`protoc` + `grpc_cpp_plugin`) to generate the required entry points?

I'm mostly wondering if more experienced grpc users have found benefits of this code generation inception or if it was just a mistake in the implementation of grpc.

Comment: To keep the generated code to a minimum? An example of what you mean would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the generated files in e.g. [here](https://github.com/jinq0123/grpc-examples-cpp/tree/master/route_guide), I don't see many template definitions being generated. Instead there are many template instantiations, some of C++ standard types like `std::unique_ptr`, and some of GRPC's own types. But the types themselves are not part of the generated code.

There is no straightforward way of removing template instantiations from C++ code, and there is no point doing so either. Whatever you would write in place if `std::unique_ptr<::grpc::ClientReader<::Namespace::GeneratedMessage>>` would either need to instantiate `std::unique_ptr` through an alias or subclass, or to be incompatible with any code expecting `std::unique_ptr`.

As for the few template definitions, they are related to `WithAsyncMethod`. This mechanism appears to automatically generate  both asynchronous and synchronous definitions of the services using C++ templates. The alternative would be to either duplicate generated code for both cases, or to slow down execution with a separate `if` inside each call.

In general, templates are such an integral part of C++ that it shouldn't be surprising to see even generated code make use of them.